# Unable to add google-play-services_lib as library

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to add google-play-services_lib as library, i have google-play-services_lib in my workspace folder, i have done importing it into my eclipse.

when i add google-play-services_lib as library it get added successfully with green tick mark.

[image]

After apply and ok when i reopen the same android tab to check if library is added successfully or not, i get red cross.

[image]

Any way to solve this!!

Comment: Just a small comment. I recently ported an app to nokiax and they don't support google play services. I'm not sure if this is the cause for your error, but I guess it's worth mentioning.

Comment: may be, but its just name of workspace folder :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your `Library` project in your workspace folder. It means in the same folder that contains your project `code`.

Comment: Just check both project properties and check whether it is in same directory after import.

Comment: They are in same folder!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

When you import google play services library into your project, check "Copy projects into workspace".

Comment: I did that while importing!

Comment: Okay. Try this alternative, 1)Click File -> Import -> Existing android project into workspace and browse in the below location for the library..  <android sdk folder >/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google play services library

Answer (score 2):

[image]

when the goole paly service lib improting to eclipse make sure
check to copy projects in to workspace.

you should have remove current google pay service lib and re import project to eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating new workspace folder and transferring all projects including library from old workspace!

Comment: that means you have putted your both project and lib. in the same directory. that's what i am saying to you!! from the beginning.